# Odd character popping up when writing to a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, character, file-writing

New to python. I'm testing out files and I'm trying to get a number (taken as raw input) to be written to a file. Then I want a function I've made to take that number as it's input parameter and perform an equation with it.

For some reason though, when writing to the file a strange character pops up. When I tried to copy-paste it to look it up, it just copied as this weird block of numbers or as an empty space.
[weird character in notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYtim.png)

Here is my code so far:

```
def function(x):
    y = x + 1
    return y

Input = raw_input('Number?')

with open('in_test.txt','w+') as inFile_test:
    inFile_test.write(Input)
    lines = inFile_test.readline()
    lines_int = [int(x) for x in lines.split()]
    print str(lines_int)

f_test = function(lines_int)
print str(f_test)
```

I've also tried changing the file format to r+, checking the encoding type in notepad (ANSI), and looking up the error that comes up.

```
    lines_int = [int(x) for x in lines.split()]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x02'
```

I'm assuming the error is caused by the weird character but I'm not sure what's causing the weird character.

Comment: Why don't you use UTF encoding?

Comment: Try adding `lines.encode('utf-8')` before initialising `lines_int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the file pointer back to the beginning.
You can check the current position of the file pointer with the tell() function.

```
with open('in_test.txt','w+') as inFile_test:
    inFile_test.write(Input)
    print inFile_test.tell()
    inFile_test.seek(0) # re-position the file pointer to the beginning
    lines = inFile_test.readline()
    lines_int = [int(x) for x in lines.split()]
    print str(lines_int)
```

Also, the call to function() is incorrect, you've defined it to accept an int but are calling it with a list argument.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the character problem. I thought the code on your line 6 was meant to fix that, taking a string/list and converting it to an int?

Comment: The list comprehension creates a list object. So  lines_int is a list of int types. So the call can be either function(lines_int[0]), or you could unpack the list like so ---  function(*lines_int)